# Communication lost between VueJS App and CEF Sharp when do a RDP

Tags: cefsharp, chromium-embedded

In my hybrid application which developed using C#, WPF, CEF, and VueJs.
On RDP, CefSharp loaded event is trigged and Vue JS components are loading fine. 
But from Vue JS application the communication to C# is failing.

```
CEF Version :  CefSharp.WPF 79.1.360
```

There are no issues when we run the same on the local computer. This issue observed only when we take a remote desktop.

Steps to reproduce the issue.

Application is running in a remote machine and we are accessing through RDP.
On the launch of the application, everything works fine.
After I disconnect the RDP and login after 1 hour, it tries to re-loads the page. UI looks fine and javascript able to call the web APIs.
Issue occurs in communication between Javascript to .net. 
I tried to call the C# .net method from JS. I am getting error as undefined.
From JS when C# .net object is undefined, I have tried JavascriptObjectRepository_Resolve on IsLoaded event. 
It also does not work.

Please let me know anyone encounters this issue and any workaround suggestions?

Comment: What does failing exactly mean? Please provide additional information, the error message your are getting, exactly what your are doing. Check the log file https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#log-file

Comment: Sure @amaitland, will include the details.

Comment: Hi @amaitland,
My colleague has posted the same issue in Gitter,
I have updated the repro steps in the question, 
please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: What exactly does `JavascriptObjectRepository_Resolve on IsLoaded event` mean? What method are you using to bind your objects? Are you using the newer `CefSharp.BindObjectAsync` method call in `javascript`? I only have a single machine for development these days so you'll probably have to debug this one yourself.